# Syntax error String method C++

Tags: c++, string, methods, syntax

I'm trying to program a text adventure game, and I have some problems with my code.

The purpose of this code is to create a method who receive a string variable and return it in upper case.

When I compile it, the only error I have is syntax error but I don't know where it come from.

Header code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class texto{


public:
   string Mayusculas(string);

};
```

Cpp code:

```
#include "Texto.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

 string texto::Mayusculas(string palabra){

    int i;
    string nueva_palabra;
    for (i = 0; i < palabra.size(); i++){

         nueva_palabra += toupper(palabra[i]);

    }

    return nueva_palabra;
}
```

The syntax errors are all in line 8 of cpp "string texto::Mayusculas(string palabra){"

```
Error   6   error C2059: error de sintaxis : ')'
Error   7   error C2143: error de sintaxis : expected ';' after '{' 
Error   5   error C2146: error de sintaxis : expected ')' after 'palabra'
Error   3   error C2146: error de sintaxis : expected ';' after 'Mayusculas'
Error   8   error C2447: '{' : falta el encabezado de función (¿lista formal de     estilo anterior?)
Error   2   error C2653: 'texto' : no es un nombre de clase o espacio de  nombres   
Error   4   error C4430: falta el especificador de tipo; se presupone int.     Nota: C++ no 
Advertencia 1   warning C4627: '#include "Texto.h"': se omite al buscar el uso del encabezado precompilado
```

Comment: You should #include <cctype> instead of <ctype.h>.

Comment: What syntax error? Please add this, plus in what file, class, and line. The compiler tells you that for a reason.

Comment: I fix it, all was about the libraries were put bad. Ty all

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer/comment:
 - You seem to be adding a character to a string where the string += is
   meant to concatenate strings...  You could try altering the
   `nueva_palabra` line to `nueva_palabra[i]=toupper(palabra[i]);` ,
   however without seeing the syntax error it is hard to see where to
   correct this.

to make the above work you would have to copy the contents of palabra to nueva palabra before being able to access the i'th item otherwise as was correctly pointed out, you will most likely have an error in your code.

Try to avoid mixing character arrays and strings if possible, you can do it, but if you are using one or the other stick to that, strings are a more C++ idiomatic way of doing things character arrays are a more C idiomatic way.

Comment: Adding a character to a string should work [just fine](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D). But you are accessing `nueva_palabra`'s `i`th element although it is empty - this is illegal and will likely result in a crash or corrupted memory.

Comment: actually yep, you are right wasnt thinking that the neva_palabra was empty, will amend the answer